# what is a meaning of q * q.adjoint() mean?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, quaternions, robotics

i'm study quaternion expression by Eigen and i found out this expression that i don't understand

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix4d A = Eigen::Matrix4d::Zero();
if (q[0] < 0)
{
     q = -q;
}
A = q * q.adjoint();
Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> eig(A);

std::cout << "Matrix \n" << A << std::endl;
std::cout << "EigenVecs \n" << eig.eigenvectors() << std::endl;
std::cout << "EigenVals\n" << eig.eigenvalues() << std::endl;

Eigen::Vector4d q_avg = eig.eigenvectors().col(3);
```

what is the meaning of q * q.adjoint(), why do that??

q is Eigen::Quaternion.

Comment: Are you asking about the _mathematical_ meaning of `q * q.adjoint()` (quaternion times its conjugate transpose)? If so, this question would likely be better suited for [Math.SE] SE, though be sure to check their posting guidelines before asking.

Comment: Is `q` a `Eigen::Quaterniond` or a `Eigen::Vector4d`? What is `M`? What is the function intended to do? Can you post a [mre]? Is this actually accumulating multiple `q`-vectors?

Comment: @chtz I edited my post, q is Eigen::Quaterniond, and M is nothing for this case.

Comment: `Eigen::Quaterniond` does not provide a subscript operator: https://godbolt.org/z/jKveq9brK. Post a [MRE]!!